# Adding the quantity part to the _ProductBox.cshtml in the views/Catalog

Tags: nopcommerce

Adding the quantity part to the _ProductBox.cshtml in the views/Catalog so that changing the quantity would reflect the changes of the quantity in shopping cart page.